# How to solve 404 error from FLASK in ajax code?

Tags: python, ajax, mongodb, flask

so ajax is calling:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/'+x"/"+y

but the error I keep getting is:
**127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2019 15:38:40] "[33mGET /-1/0.2?_=1550608718380 HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -**

I have tried everything I could and even extensively searched StackOverflow before posting.

x and y are suppose to be values between -1 and 1. from the error log it is obvious its reading the numbers. So im thinking it has something to do with FLASK. what im trying to do is have flask retrieve those x and y values but I dont think its receiving them somehow.

When I ran that same Mongo query in jupyter notebook it has no problem retrieving that data. so its definetly has nothing to do with Mongo.

I have used that almost exact same javascript code and flask method in another project and that had no problems whatsoever

This is my flask code:

`@app.route("/<int:mn>/<int:mx>")
def polarity(mn,mx):
        pol=tweet.aggregate([{"$match":{"polarity":{"$gte":mn,"$lte":mx}}}]);
        return dumps(pol)`

Javascript:

```js
    $.ajax({

        cache: false,
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'+x.val()+"/"+y.val(),
    type:'get',
     dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
        $.each(data,function(i,data){
            results.push(data);
            $('.latest-tweet').hide()
        });
        console.log(results)

    // createCards.dom(results)
} 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for `y = 0.2` is not an int. This is causing it to not find the end point `/<int>/<int>` because it is looking for `/<int>/<float>`

Change your endpoint to

```
@app.route("/<string:mn>/<string:mx>")
def polarity(mn,mx):
    try:
        mn = float(mn)
        mx = float(mx)
    except ValueError:
        return Response(status=400)
    pol=tweet.aggregate([{"$match":{"polarity":{"$gte":mn,"$lte":mx}}}]);
        return dumps(pol)
```

This will allow you to deal with negative floats

Comment: Test it with both ints on the initial endpoint and see what you get. Is it the same error or is it a CORS error instead?

Comment: I had to clear the cache thats why it did not work the first time. so nowyou helped me solve half of my issue. but the other half is that its not accepting negative floats. does python even accept negative floats ? its working for any values between 0 and 1

Comment: It is seeing that input as a String rather than as a negative float. I'll update my answer to show you a solution

Comment: Not a problem glade It fixed the issue